# Postgresql date_part on muliple records

Tags: postgresql

I've multiple records whit same **who** value and different when
table:

I've an attendance table, with this structure:

> who | when | why
>
> "when" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
>
> "who" text,

I need to calculate the difference between each record for the same **who**.

I've tried :

```
DATE_PART('hour', table."when"::timestamp - table."when"::timestamp)
```

but don't seems to work.

i.e.

```
A | 2017-03-01 08:30 
A | 2017-03-01 12:30 
B | 2017-03-01 08:30 
B | 2017-03-01 12:30
```

Need to get total hours for A and B separated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html) in order access the value of the "previous" row:

```
select who, 
       when, 
       when - lag(when) over (partition by who order by when) as diff
from the_table
order by who, when;
```

If you only ever have two rows per who, or just care for the first and last value of `when`, use a simple aggregation:

```
select who, 
       max(when) - min(when)
from the_table 
group by who
order by who;
```